# How to add an image in textfield in sencha touch

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I want to add a small image in the text field in sencha touch. For example a small user icon in the username text field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create your textfield like this:

```
{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    cls: 'username',
    fieldLabel : 'Username', // works for ExtJS
    label : 'Username' // works for Sencha Touch
}
```

and add this to your CSS

```
.username .x-form-text, .username .x-form-field {
    background: url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/12/User_icon_2.svg/48px-User_icon_2.svg.png) no-repeat left;
    background-size: contain;
    padding-left: 25px;
}
.username .x-form-field { /* Adding more padding for Sencha Touch only */
    padding-left: 50px;
}
```

Comment: I was looking for something inbuilt. But this looks fine. Thanks..

Comment: @user2842237 This _is_ the officially supported, builtin how-to-do-it!