# How to add image in textfield in sencha

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

Can anybody tell how to add image in text field in sencha touch

I want to show image and textfield
 image User id

Thanks

Comment: possibly duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26447925/how-to-add-an-image-in-textfield-in-sencha-touch

Answer (score 0):

Use css to do this.

```
.imagefield .x-form-field {
  background: url(../icons/icon.png) no-repeat;  /*your file path*/
  background-size: contain;
 }
```

add property cls: 'imagefield' in your component.